# How to generate a *.dess file using the DIVINE Model Checker?

Tags: model-checking

I have been trying to use the DIVINE4 model checker to verify llvm bc file. But when I read the DIVINE documentation I don't find this option, is this feature no longer supported in DIVINE 4? Or has the name been changed?

Let me know if this feature is supported or tell me the new options, if any.